# Несколько autotools проектов в одном

Tags: build-automation

Возможно ли написать Makefile.am или configure.ac, который будет "корневым".

Имеется следующая иерархия, необходимо сборать все проекты, но желательно делать это с помощью autoconf или automake

root
root/proj1
root/proj2
root/proj3

Comment: Месье знает толк...